# What is app control panel

Tags: java, php, android, controls

I am new in android development ,My question is 
what does it mean to have an android app with a control panel  , Is it possible to control app after release ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

usually when somebody wants to make a mobile application, he creates a control panel using any back-end (php, java, node.js ...etc)
so he can control the API (if your app uses API call), he may also want to disable the application, so in each run in the application side, an API call will be invoked to check for availability.

you can do more complicated things but that is the basic